# How to read Request Header in custom authorizer written in Java 8 in AWS API Gateway

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create token based custom authorizer in AWS API Gateway with Java 8. But not sure how to read Token which client will be sending in Request Header.
In following code, Token POJO Class with be mapped to Request Body. But I need to read the Token from Request Header.

```
public AccessPolicy handleRequest (Token t, Context context) {

        System.out.println("Token : "+t.getToken());
        context.getLogger().log("Token : "+t.getToken());
        context.
        if(t.getToken()!=null) {
            AccessPolicy policy = new AccessPolicy();

            Statement statement = new Statement();
            statement.setEffect(t.getToken());

            List<String> action = new ArrayList<String>();
            action.add("execute-api:Invoke");
            statement.setAction(action);

            List<String> resource = new ArrayList<String>();
            resource.add("*");
            statement.setResource(resource);

            policy.setVersion("2012-10-17");
            policy.setStatement(statement);

            return policy;
        }
        return null;
}

public class AccessPolicy {

    private String Version;
    private Statement Statement;
    public String getVersion() {
        return Version;
    }
    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.Version = version;
    }
    public Statement getStatement() {
        return Statement;
    }
    public void setStatement(Statement statement) {
        this.Statement = statement;
    }
}
```